# amazon-Cloudformation metric alarm prevent to be on alert when there is no information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an alarm for a metric in cloudformation

So I have my `MetricFilter` with my `Alarm` Like next:

```
{
    "logMetric": {
        "Type" : "AWS::Logs::MetricFilter",
        "Properties" : {
            "FilterPattern" : "[ERROR, WARNING, FATAL, Exception]",
            "LogGroupName" : "/logapp",
            "MetricTransformations" : [ {
                "MetricValue": "1",
                "MetricNamespace": "ErrorLogs/app",
                "MetricName": "AppLogMetric"
            } ]
            }
    }, 
    "AppLogAlert": {
        "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
        "Properties": {
        "ActionsEnabled": "true",
        "AlarmActions":  ["arn"],
        "AlarmDescription": "trigger alert when an error is received into the app",
        "AlarmName": "app-ErrorLog-alert",
        "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
        "MetricName": "AppLogMetric",
        "Namespace": "ErrorLogs/app",
        "Period": 60,
        "Statistic": "Maximum",
        "Threshold": 1
        }
    }
}
```

This is creating both `AWS::Logs::MetricFilter` and `AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm` and it looks great, it goes into `Alarm` status when there is more than 1 detection in the last minute.

The problem is that when there are no logs with those filters, the alarm does not go back to `OK` status, as the graph does not show "0" alerts, its just blank space Is there any way to make this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is that you set [TreatMissingData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-treatmissingdata) as `notBreaching`.

I think your usecase is similar to this one for kms: [Creating an Amazon CloudWatch Alarm to Detect Usage of a Customer Master Key that is Pending Deletion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/deleting-keys-creating-cloudwatch-alarm.html)